# Is it safe to use conntrack on Linux bridge devices?

Tags: network, linux, ip-spoofing, segmentation

I have a server with a number of Linux *bridge* devices for use with groups of virtual machines - some internet-routed, some intentionally unrouted. I have *stateful* firewalling in place for traffic traversing across and between those bridges. Excerpt:

```
ip6tables -A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A FORWARD -m conntrack ! --ctstate NEW -j DROP
ip6tables -A FORWARD -i br21 -o br21 -m physdev --physdev-out vm21a -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A FORWARD -j DROP
```

*Practically*, this works. All connections that should work do work, non-spoofed connections are allowed or dropped in accordance with my port-based firewall rules. See this [Q&A in Unix&Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499756/how-does-iptable-work-with-linux-bridge) that for practical requisites & implications of using iptables on bridges in the first place.

On the *security* side of things, I may have overlooked important side-effects.

- Untrusted users can execute privileged code on virtual machines attached to some of my bridges.
- Goal: Untrusted users should not be able to learn about or interfere with connections on different bridges.

I suspect they can, because my fragment reassembly & *conntrack* table.. looks like *one* big table, no zones, no segmentation. Is this a real risk in my setup? If so, can I meaningfully mitigate it, by any means short of distributing the VMs to different hosts?

I am looking for answers that clearly spell out which subsystem(s) above which kernel version allow the suggested assertion or solution (but potentially referring back to [U&L](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bridge+iptables)/[SF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bridge+iptables) for technical details). Clearly things have changed a lot over the years; One [quote that predates](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/1246379267.3749.42.camel@blaa/) among other work, the ability to create net namespaces:

> conntrack is inherently a security hole when used as part of bridging,
> because it ignores the Ethernet header so two unrelated connections
> can be tracked as one.